# Whats the best way to integration test a facebook application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, tdd, capybara

So, I have a facebook App that I am testing.  I'd like to test a user's interaction on the app, and I'm having an issue.

The user flow that I'm testing is relatively simple:  when a user comes to the in-page facebook app, if they already like the page in which the app is located they will see x-content, if they have not yet liked the page, they will be met with a like gate.  My goal is to confirm that my users are able to see certain text once they have like the facebook page.

my test:

```
describe "facebook" do
  it "visit and like page", :vcr do
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    visit "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Testpage/433439410073990?id=433439410073990&sk=app_454512097948559"
    within('#login_form') do
        fill_in "email", with: FB_EMAIL
        fill_in "pass", with: FB_PASSWORD
        click_on "Log In"
    end
    page.should have_content('Testpage')

    within('#timelineHeadlineLikeButton') do
      click_on 'like'
    end
  end
end
```

my problem is that I can't figure out how to get capybara to like the page.

How are you integration testing you facebook applications?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the complete example.

**test.rb**
(You can add it to a initializer and add it if the enviroment is test).

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

  FACEBOOK_INFO = {
    "id"=> "220449",
    "email" => "nypee@facebook.com",
  }

  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {
    "uid" => '112345',
    "provider" => 'facebook',
    "user_info" => {"name" => "Nype Aylor", "nickname" => 'Aylor'},
    "credentials" => {"token" => 'plataformatec'},
    "extra" => {"user_hash" => FACEBOOK_INFO}
  }
```

This simulates the call to omniauth. 
So in your test, when you simulate a click to the facebook button, 
the response you will get is the one from

`OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook].`

I think is the best way to integrate testing with Facebook